# Azure table storage exception handling

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-table-storage

When handling a `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException` raised by Azure Table Storage, is there a way of determining what the error is without querying the `HTTPStatusCode` and the `ErrorCode`. For example when trying to insert a duplicate entity the following is raised by Azure :

> HTTPStatusCode : 409
>
> ErrorCode : "EntityAlreadyExists"

Is there an enumeration of these error codes that I can switch on rather than directly querying against both the (int) `HTTPStatusCode` and (string) `ErrorCode` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`TableErrorCodeStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.protocol.tableerrorcodestrings_members.aspx) class which lists all the possible error codes.